# Tips on speeding up hierarchical linkage clustering algorithm

Tags: algorithms, clustering

I implemented a hierarchical linkage algorithm for a set of 5,000 points. Each point is defined with a longitude and a latitude.

I read about this algorithm [here](https://statsandr.com/blog/clustering-analysis-k-means-and-hierarchical-clustering-by-hand-and-in-r/#single-linkage).

These are the steps:

1. Compute distance matrix between all points (great-circle distance, not Euclidean)
2. Find the pair of points with the minimum distance between them
3. If the minimum distance is larger than a threshold value

   - the algorithm finishes
4. Otherwise

   - The two points are merged, and removed from the list of points.
   - The center point of this pair is added to the list of points
5. Go back to 1

I do not consider single, complete, etc. types of linkage, since the points are substituted by a central point. Therefore, the distance is just the distance between all points (instead of point-cluster).

It runs okay for small amount of pairs, but it takes 1 second per iteration as soon as I run it for 5,000 points; potentially 83 minutes although it probably stops halfway due to the distance threshold.

Although I use [Haversine formulation](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) in the calculation of distances, it does not change much if I use a simple Euclidean approach; it then takes 1 second for 3 iterations.

Am I making a mistake in understanding and implementing this algorithm? If not, are there ways in which this could be sped up?

I am using MATLAB R2018b.

Thank you!

Comment: (In the article, I don't find *5. go to step 1: filling the distance matrix from scratch*.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  After you merge two points, you can update the distances of just the affected nodes, without having to recompute all pairs of distances again.  That will be vastly faster.